# XML generation from SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm generating an XML file from SQL data. One of the Tags in the XML is a concatenation of multiple SQL columns. I need to insert a line break between each column value (all values will still be in the same XML tag, but separated by line breaks. I'm unable to insert these line breaks however. My SQL looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @FreeFormColumns nvarchar(max);
SET @FreeFormColumns = STUFF ((
 SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME
 FROM
  tblColumnNames
 FOR XML PATH('')),
  1,1, 11)

SET @SQLString = 'select CONCAT(' + @FreeFormColumns + ') AS FRF
from tblMain
```

Key:
`COLUMN_NAME` in `tblColumnNames` contains the names of columns in `tblMain`

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you really mean to write `from MS Access` in your title?

Comment: Indeed, why is MS Access in the title?

Comment: @TT. Sorry, I'll edit the title and say SQL instead. Actually, I'm calling the SQL code from MS Access. So when I began writing the question on SO, I started off with providing the details of how I'm executing the SQL code, but then decided to skip that bit since I realised that that's not where the issue lies. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @TT. Can you please let me know if there is a way of inserting these line breaks through MS Access though? So say, while importing all the SQL data into Access I insert a special character between column values. And then within Access, before writing these values to `.xml` file, I replace the special character with Access's notation for a line break? So that within the final `.xml` file each of these values appears on a different line.

Comment: Ouch no. I'm no fan of Access. Did the answer of bheltzel not help you? Perhaps you need `CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)` instead of just `CHAR(10)`? If it didn't help you out, in what way did the answer come short?

Comment: @TT. Unfortunately it didn't. I've replied to him about it. The solution only seems to insert a line feed between column names in the select statement, not in the actual values of those columns. For now, I've implemented the solution I proposed above which seems to work (used `vbCrLf` in Access for inserting a line feed). Except that, the xml (as rendered in IE) doesn't show the values on separate lines but the 'View as source' does.

Comment: Did you my answer do any better?

Comment: Line-breaks are very special... One the one hand, you have to know, that line breaks differ from system to system. Secondly you did not tell us, how the XML is created (show code and example!). And finally I do not get **where** and **how** you want to display these created values. Sometimes everything is fine, but the displaying tool does not show line breaks.

Comment: @Shnugo You are absolutely right! I just found out that the line breaks are being inserted correctly in the code (used `vBcRlf` in `MS Access`). But, `XML` does not have anything in it to format the data. Hence, to be able to show the line breaks in the browser (using `IE`), `HTML` would need to be used.

Comment: @TT. Your answer around `Char(10)+Char(13)`, does work in SQL..but it would only display line breaks when 'results to text' or 'results to file' option is selected on SSMS. Unfortunately, I can't use those options since they truncate the data if the string is huge. Nonetheless, MS Access seems to fix the problem in this case. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHAR(10)` to insert a line feed. `CHAR(13)` is used for carriage returns.

```
DECLARE @FreeFormColumns nvarchar(max);
SET @FreeFormColumns = STUFF ((
SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME + CHAR(10)
FROM
    tblColumnNames
FOR XML PATH('')),
    1,1, 11)

SET @SQLString = 'select CONCAT(' + @FreeFormColumns + ') AS FRF
from tblMain'
```

Comment: that only seems to insert a line feed between column names in the select statement, not in the actual values of those columns

Answer (score 0):

How about this? This selects the values with a newline appended to it. I don't know what that'll give in your context, but it's a try anyway.

```
DECLARE @FreeFormColumns nvarchar(max);
SET @FreeFormColumns = STUFF ((
SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+'='+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)'+
FROM
    tblColumnNames
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    1,1, 11);
```

Comment: aah yet to try this one. will get back to you once I've done so! cheers

Comment: @V.Asher Any better now? I'm guessing not, cf Shnugo's comment.